# Function $T:X \rightarrow X$ with least Lipschitz constant, for which $\sup_{x \in X}d(T(x),x) \le r$.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $X=(X,d)$ be a metric space and $r \ge 0$.

> **Question 1.** What is a good **upper-bound** (the smaller the better) for $\inf_T Lip(T)$ where $Lip(T) := \underset{x,x' \in X,\;x \ne x'}{\sup}\; \frac{d(T(x),T(x'))}{d(x,x')}$, and the infimum is taken over all functions $T:X \rightarrow X$ such that $\underset{x \in X}{\sup}\;d(T(x),x) \le r$ ?
>
> **Question 2.** Same question when $X$ is a normed vector space, e.g $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with an $\ell_p$-norm, especially the cases $p=1,2,\infty$.

**N.B.:** Of course, these bounds would depend on the parameter $r$. Also note that the an upper bound of $1$ is trivial and uninformative (gotten by taken $T =I_X$, the identity function on $X$).

Comment: Nice question! I guess your $Lip(X)$ should be $Lip(T)$?

Comment: Good catch. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: May I ask how you got to this question? It is cool, but I would have never asked myself this question.

Comment: $Lip(T)$ is the $W_1$-contraction constant for the (deterministic!) Markov kernel $K_T:X \rightarrow \mathcal P(X)$ defined by $K_T(x)=\delta_{T(x)}$. $W_1$ is the order-1 Wasserstein distance on $\mathcal P(X)$, the probability distributions on $X$. Note that $W_1(K_T(x),K_T(x')) = d(T(x), T(x')) \le Lip(T)d(x,x')$.

Answer (score 4):

If $r\geq\sup_{x,x'\in X} d(x,x')$, then the infimum is equal to $0$ (as we can simply take a constant function.

On the other hand, if $\sup_{x,x'\in X} d(x,x')=\infty$, then your infimum is equal to 1. This we see from
$$ \frac{d(T(x),T(x'))}{d(x,x')} \geq \frac{d(x,x')-d(T(x),x) -d(x', T(x')) }{d(x,x')} \geq 1 - \frac{2r}{d(x,x')} $$
and letting $d(x,x') \rightarrow \infty$ yields the desired result (when combined with your trivial upper bound). In particular this gives you the result for any (non-trivial) normed space.

My guess is that for general metric spaces it becomes extremely nasty (just play around with some metric spaces consisting of finitely many points). If you consider finite metric spaces and take $r< \min_{x,x'\in X \ : \ x\neq x'} d(x,x')$, then your infimum will be equal to $1$. On the other hand if it is bigger, then it will depend on the relative position of those points to each other.

**Added:** The computation above shows that the infimum above is always bounded from below by $\max\{0, 1-2r/diam(X)\}$. So that would be best we can get and sometimes we get it (for example for intervals with the Euclidean metric or for all normed vector spaces). However, considering finite metric spaces shows that this lower bound is not always attained.

**Added:** Another example that in general we cannot hope to get a nice formula. Consider the circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$. We define the metric via the length of the minimal connecting curve. Now pick $r<\pi/2$. We show that the infimum over the lipschitz constants is equal to $1$.

Assume by contradiction that there exists a contraction $T$ on $S^1$ satisfying the condition with $r<\pi/2$.

Let us define 
$$A_1:=\{ e^{2\pi x} \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ x\in (0;1/2)\}, \quad A_2:=\{ e^{2\pi x} \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ x\in (1/2;1)\}$$
$$ A_3:=\{ e^{2\pi x} \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ x\in (-1;-1/2)\}, \quad  A_4:=\{ e^{2\pi x} \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ x\in (-1/2;0)\}  $$
Wlog we may assume that $T(1)=1$ (otherwise precompose with a rotation). In addition we may assume wlog $T(-1)\in A_1 \cup A_2$. But from $r<\pi/2$ we get $T(-1)\in A_2$.

As $1$ is a fixed point and $T$ is a contraction, we get $T(-i)\in A_1 \cup A_4$. However, as $r<\pi/2$, we must have $T(-i)\in A_4$.

As $T(-1)\in A_2$ and $T(-i)\in A_4$ we get $d(T(-1), T(-i)) > \pi/2$ and therefore
$$ \frac{d(T(-1), T(-i))}{d(-1, -i)} > \frac{\pi/2}{\pi/2} =1. $$
This is a contradiction as $T$ is a contraction.

**Added:** On the other hand, if we consider the metric space $(-1;1)$ with the Euclidean metric, then we have the map $T: (-1;1) \rightarrow (-1;1), \ T(x) = \left(1-r \right)x$. We have $\vert T(x) - x\vert = r \vert x \vert < r$ and $Lip(T)=1-r = 1-\frac{2r}{diam((-1;1))}$.

Comment: Great. Should have thought of this. Thanks. So, it seems the question only becomes interesting for $r \le diam(X) < \infty$. Any thoughts for this scenario ?

Comment: I have no idea. And in fact, I guess you would really need to know the geometry of the space.

Comment: $(\mathbb{R}^n, \ell_p)$ is a normed space and the case of normed spaces is treated in my answer (the infimum is equal to $1$). However, if you consider finite metric spaces (eg graphs), then you will see that you can have some $r$ which will force the infimum to be $1$. I leave it to you to come up with an explicite example.

Comment: OK, sorry didn't read your answer all through.

Comment: BTW, first nontrivial non-NVS non-discrete example with finite diameter: $(X,d)=$ circle equipped with geodesic (arc-length) distance.

Comment: By the Banach fixed point theorem we have a unique fixed point. We can parametrize the circle (let's say diameter equal $1$) starting from the fixed point and get that any "good" contraction (a competitor for the infimum) on the circle comes from a contraction $f:(-\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}] \rightarrow [0; \frac{1}{2}]$ with $f(-\frac{1}{2})=f(\frac{1}{2})$ and $f(0)=0$ and $\min\{\vert x \vert + f(x), \ 1 - f(x) - \vert x \vert \}\leq r$. I am not quite sure how solve this, but I looks traceable. Will come back to it, when I have time.

Comment: Also you can see that this is very much different from the interval case (which one easily checks that the infimum is $1-2r/diam$ for $0\leq r \leq diam/2$). This is kind of interesting, because it tells us that the expression $1-2r/diam$ is sometimes attained (note that I proved in my answer that this is a lower bound for the infimum).

Comment: Your construction of $f$ is not clear. BFPT applied to what ? Also, $0 \in im(f)$ but $f$ is supposed to be a function $circle \rightarrow circle$. This a typo ? "We can parametrize the circle ..." something seems missing in the phrase.

Comment: BFPT to the circle. This gives you a unique fixed point (wlog equal to $1\in S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$). We parametrize by arclength starting from the fixed point ($(-\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}] \rightarrow S^1, \ x\mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$). Representing the contraction in the this new coordinates yields $f$.

Comment: As it is a contraction, the image cannot be in both upper and lower part of the circle, thus wlog I assumed it is in the upper part.

Comment: I gave a slightly nicer proof for the circle. For $r<diam/4$ we get that the infimum of the lipschitz constants is again equal to $1$. Which supports again what I wrote above that in general you will not get better than $1$.

Comment: You example on the interval $X=((-1, 1),|\cdot|)$ extends to the case where $X$ is contained in some ball in a normed vector-space. Indeed, for $0 < r \le diam(X)/2$, simply take $T(x) = (1-2r/diam(X))x$, and note that
$$
d(T(x),x) = r\|x\| \le 2r\|x\|/diam(X)\le r,and 
$$
$\|T\|_{Lip} = 1-2r/diam(X) \in [0, 1)$.

Comment: Sorry in what I wrote above, I'm also assuming $X$ is a **cone**, so that $T(X) \subseteq X$. This is not the case in the circle example you considered.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a cone. Also in all the examples I considered I had $T(X)\subseteq X$ (I mean $T:X\rightarrow X$), or what do you mean was not the case in my examples?

Comment: Sorry, there is a mixup. I meant the specific $T$ in the example map I defined 2 comments above. Call it $T_0$ instead, if you will. This function is defined by $T_0(x) := (1-2r/diam(X))x$. If $X$ is a circle, then $T_0(X) \not\subseteq X$ (unless $r=0$). However if $X$ is a cone, then $T_0(X) \subseteq X$. **N.B.:** A subset $X$ of a vector space $V$ is called a cone iff $\alpha X \subseteq X$ for all $\alpha \ge 0$.

Comment: Ahh, I missed the comment with your example. Yes, of course it extends to that case. However, the cone condition is extremly strong, I mean you impose a linear structur.

Comment: Well, things can be very general and nonlinear even with the cone restriction. E.g, think of psd matrices.

Comment: I do not quite agree. You need the ambient space to carry a linear structure, that is for me a strong condition. Also the cone condition is not stable under perturbation.